# mdutil using a lot of CPU after upgrading to Ventura 13.4.1

Tags: spotlight, cpu

I have a new, fairly clean MacBook Air that was running calmly before upgrading to 13.4.1. Just after doing so, my `md*` processes starting using a lot of cpu. A fresh boot with nothing running but Activity Monitor now uses about 50% cpu.

When I turn off Spotlight with `sudo mdutil -a -I off`, CPU usage returns to normal (less than 5% CPU), If I turn it on again with `sudo mdutil -a -I on`, CPU usage returns to about 50%, with no applications launched.

Two questions about this 'fix', please.

Is there any potentially negative consequence to leaving `mdutil` off? I don't really know what it does.

Is there a better fix for this? Spotlight is the main way I access applications and I'd like to keep the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running any command you should read the `man` page. By reading `man mdutil`, you will discover that the purpose of mdutil is to manage the metadata stores used by Spotlight.

I don't think you used the command with a capital `I`. I am assuming you used `sudo mdutil -a -i off` which turns Spotlight indexing off for all disk volumes.

There is a very definite negative consequence - Spotlight will not index your disks and so new content will not be found by Spotlight and Finder searches!

The fix is patience whilst macOS completes its indexing. Leave it running overnight.

Comment: ah so this explains why things got significantly worse when I first turned mdutil off and on again - I guess it began the indexing process all over again. cool thanks I'll turn it on overnight tonight (east Asia time) and report back how the cpu use changes.